# SQL get max date and join on other table

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, subquery, max

Sorry that this is somewhat a duplicate but I've been through the other answers which has helped me get to the SQL below but I can't figure out how manage the join with the subquery that gets the max date.

```
SELECT
mo_number, -- from systems_test_status, everything else from combiner_test_data
CDT.test_index,
CDT.datetime,
lumina_current_1,
power_reading_1,
lumina_current_2,
power_reading_2,
lumina_current_3,
power_reading_3,
lumina_current_4,
power_reading_4
most_recent,
step_pass_status

FROM combiner_test_data AS CDT

INNER JOIN systems_test_status ON CDT.test_index = systems_test_status.test_index

--JOIN(select
--  test_index,
--  MAX(datetime) AS most_recent_time
--  FROM combiner_test_data AS subCDT
--  GROUP BY test_index) as joinCDT on CDT.test_index = joinCDT.test_index
--  and CDT.datetime = joinCDT.most_recent_time

WHERE lumina_current_2 > 12
```

The join and the subquery work fine separately but together they only output a few rows whereas I'd expect a few thousand. I've commented out the subquery in the example above. The only reason I need a an inner join is to return systems_test_status.mo_number by joining on test_index.

Running it without the subquery correctly returns about 48,000 records for stress testing electrical assets. Many of these records pertain to the same asset (the reference for which is test_index). Each asset gets tested many times.

Running the subquery alone correctly returns the most recent test date for each asset.

I'm trying to get just the most recent test for each asset.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you expect a few thousand?

Comment: Adding back in that subquery via an INNER JOIN should give you only `combiner_test_data` for each test_index where the 'datetime' is only the most recent `datetime`. Perhaps... you aren't wanting the just the most recent time, but the most recent `date` which has many times in it? This is just a guess since there isn't enough information here to help you. We would need to see some sample data and your anticipated output from this query to properly diagnose.

Comment: Sorry both, OP updated for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: Your query seems correct. Result should be less than 48000 and you get less than 48000. So can you describe something specifically pointing the problem?

Comment: Do you have NULLs in your datetime?

Comment: @ Serif Emek - I mean way less, like 6. I know there should be a few thousand

Comment: @ Fruitbat - there won't be any nulls. Cheers

Comment: How many from subquery but adding lumina_current_2 > 12 ?
this one I mean;
select
test_index, MAX(datetime) 
FROM combiner_test_data 
where
lumina_current_2 > 12  
GROUP BY test_index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `row_number` function to set the max date row to 1 and then select the record. The solution assumes `mo_number` uniquely identifies each asset. If not, change the `partition by` in the `row_number` function to the column that uniquely identifies the asset.

```
select * from
(
SELECT
mo_number, 
combiner_test_data
CDT.test_index,
CDT.datetime,
lumina_current_1,
power_reading_1,
lumina_current_2,
power_reading_2,
lumina_current_3,
power_reading_3,
lumina_current_4,
power_reading_4
most_recent,
step_pass_status,
row_number() over(partition by mo_number order by datetime desc) as rn
FROM combiner_test_data AS CDT
INNER JOIN systems_test_status ON CDT.test_index = systems_test_status.test_index
WHERE lumina_current_2 > 12
) t
where rn = 1;
```